# How can I pass dataurl into browser url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I want to pass dataUrl into Browser Url.But dataUrl is to long.How can I do this?

```
var chart = $('#con').highcharts();
canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), chart.getSVG())

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

$("#mylink").attr("href","exmple.com?"+"img="+img);

<a id="mylink" href="">My link</a>
```

Comment: Is there any way you can use a POST request instead (and just get your content in the body)? Do you have control of the server?

Comment: I want pass through get method.Can I short the dataurl through encode or decode?